# using return of async function in view()

Tags: mithril.js

I previously had a simple component that looked something like this, but previously the getIsLoggedIn method was synchronous. We recently had to change that method to async, so I tried adding the await keyword to it and changing the view() to be async view(), but this doesnt seem to work:

```
const welcomePageComponent = {
   messages: {
     msg1: 'message if logged in',
     msg2: 'message if not logged in',
   },
   view({ state }) {
   let isLoggedIn = getIsloggedIn();
   let myMsg  = isLoggedIn ? this.messages.msg1 : this.messages.msg2;
   return m('#welcome', [
     m('.semi-trans-blk-panel', [
       m('.welcome-wrapper', [
         m('h4.welcomeMsg', [
           m('br'), myMsg  
         ])
       ])
     ])
   ]);
  }
}
```

How can I go about calling an async function and using its return value inside my view()?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the application view must be computed synchronously on each draw; if a promise returned by a view were to trigger a new view computation on resolution, the next computation would still resolve to a promise, so you'd be stuck in a loop.

The solution is to instantiate an extra data point to track whether the promise has resolved, and an `oninit` lifecycle method to call the promise and change the relevant data once, on initialisation, and then redraw. Finally, we modify the view function to return nothing unless the authentication data is available.

```js
const welcomePageComponent = {
   messages: {
     msg1: 'message if logged in',
     msg2: 'message if not logged in',
   },
   isLoggedIn: undefined,
   isResolved: false,
   
   async oninit({ state }) {
     state.isLoggedIn = await getIsLoggedIn();
     
     state.isResolved = true;
   },
   view({ state }) {
     const myMsg  = isLoggedIn ? state.messages.msg1 : state.messages.msg2;
     
     return (
       state.isLoggedIn &&
         m('#welcome', [
           m('.semi-trans-blk-panel', [
             m('.welcome-wrapper', [
               m('h4.welcomeMsg', [
                 m('br'), myMsg  
               ])
             ])
           ])
         ])
     )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Running the sample above, I was getting an error that await can only be used inside an async method, so I added the async keyword to the oninit() method. This however was still not working for me. Instead I changed the oninit() to:

`oninit({ state }){
     getIsLoggedIn().then(res => {
        state.isLoggedIn = res;
        state.isResolved = true;
     });
}`


and that seems to have fixed my issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah fantastic. That amounts to what I intended 